# Por que o IDLE não termina a execução do programa automaticamente?

Tags: python, ide

Acredito que seja mais por curiosidade. 
Ao contrário das outras IDE's, o IDLE mantém o programa "aberto" mesmo após o fim da sua execução, enquanto em outras IDE's eu preciso colocar algo como 'input()' ao fim para o programa não ser encerrado até que eu entre com algum valor.

Alguém saberia me explicar o porquê do IDLE ter esse comportamento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso se deve ao fato de que o IDLE usa o próprio console do Python para executar seus programas, linha por linha. Portanto, quando a execução de seu programa termina, o IDLE não sai do Python automaticamente, pois o IDLE trabalha com o modo interativo do Python, isto é, ele executa todos os comandos enviados por uma entrada de texto(terminal ou stdin) e vai processando-os na medida que são digitados.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, o IDLE termina sim a execução dos programas.

O problema é que ele tem dois componentes básicos: o console Python (conhecido como "modo interativo") e o editor. Programas carregados no editor podem ser executados normalmente com o comando "Run > Run module" ou pelo atalho "F5".

As saídas serão exibidas no console, mas o programa em si será executado e encerrado como em qualquer outro lugar, salvo em caso de erros.

Já no console, como já foi dito, você entra com uma sequência de comandos, um depois do outro, que são executados à cada entrada.

Answer (score 0):

A vantagem disso é que as variáveis e funções globais do programa continuam acessíveis. Dar uma olhada nelas pode ser útil, principalmente se o programa terminou mas não funcionou como esperado.